# html Table Pagination + Checkbox Display Filter

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table of contents which has working pagination and a input checkbox when selected filters the table contents.

Although when filtered the pagination buttons do not stay consistent with the amount of items in the table. When selecting one of the paginated numbers it is showing items not relevant to the box's when checked.

Comment: see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yqxupt4c/

Comment: I would of posted the code but its very large.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your custom pagination class is overriding the results you set when you click on the pagination links (your 'active-class' is setting the rows to show).  You'll have to re-run your filter after you click on paginate link.

Else, you can assign a different class for your filter which you can set the css as `display: hidden`.  You can then set the pagination `active-class` to ignore those rows containing your class.